# How to prove isomorphism using Pebble games?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, game-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a relational language and no relational symbols have an arity greater than $S$.
If the second player has a winning strategy for the game $G^S_\infty (A,B)$ and $|A|=|B|\leq S+1$.

I want to show that $A\cong B$.

($S$ is the number of pebble pairs)

First, I defined a function $f: A\rightarrow B$ such that $f$ is a one-to-one correspondence.
Then make $f$ keep the structure by defining:

If $(\overline{\alpha_i}:\overline{a_j})\in E^A_k \Rightarrow (\overline{\beta_i}:\overline{f(a_j)})\in E^B_k $

($1\leq i\leq S , 1\leq j\leq |A|$)

By $\alpha_i:a_j$ I mean the pebble $\alpha_i$ is moved in element $a_j$.

Because the number of arities is at most $S$, this is an isomorphism.

I don't know why this is not correct as I have not used the fact that $|A|=|B|\leq S+1$

Is that because in the first-order logic every finite structure can be characterized up to isomorphism by a first-order sentence that needs $|A|+1$ variables?

Comment: hi Arlin; apologies for my ignorance, but may I ask what the definition of $G_\infty^S(A,B)$ is? (or at least for a reference?)

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to mention. It is the pebble game with $S$ pair of pebbles. This is exercise 3.3.7 of the book "finite model theory" by Ebinghaus and Flum.